# How to call Java classes from JSP

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two JSP files, one for getting the user input and the other for printing the result.
I have a class file called getdata.java. How should I access that class when the user inputs something and print the result in the result page?

/// getdata.java when user click button it redirect to result page..

```
<form action="Result.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="textname" /><br></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/> remove
```

//// class file

```
public class On_Classes {

    public void  printData()
    {
        ....
    }

}
```

/// result page

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might help? http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0508.html
Unless you wanted to link to the java page? If so upload the java class to the WEB-INF directory and then in the form action make it link to /servlet/classname?

Or if you wanted to retrieve form data:
String resName = request.getParameter("formfieldname");
in the class.

Comment: thank for your quick reply::
there is no classes folder in my WEB-INF directory. when i manually create ant put it there ,there is a error :: 
really confuse::

Comment: Hmm, first of all. what is you're host? cPanel powered?, if its cPanel powered, just upload it into the WEB-INF directory in public_html? if not, what IDE are you using to compile it?

Comment: Oh sorry, just checked tags, and you're using eclipse, if you browse the build directory when using eclipse, you should see a file ending with .war, upload that to your site/host

Comment: there is no .war file in my build directory. i used tomcat as a server...

can't imagine wht's going on:::

Comment: Have a look at http://objectmix.com/java/75371-how-deploy-servlet-after-creating-eclipse.html

Comment: @user361045, With Eclipse, the compiled code is less obvious in the package explorer than the source files.  Right-click on the project, and click "refresh" to see what exists since your last build.  You can always go to the OS and look at how the project is laid out from there.  Look for *.class files.

Comment: Hello, if your trying to access a class. you can import it using the import statement then create a new instance of it or, you can access it statically (by changing the function in the class you want to access to static) and e.g ClassYouWantToAccess.functionName(String msg);